# What is a supermicro JSATA "sideband" cable rectangular 8 pin port used for?

Tags: motherboard, supermicro

I am replacing my old server motherboard with newer one, which has a JSATA connector which can be connected to 4 SATA drives using "Internal MiniSAS HD to 4 SATA with Sideband" cable.

This is how the cable looks like on supermicro website: https://store.supermicro.com/supermicro-internal-minisas-hd-to-4-sata-with-sideband-90-90-75-75-75cm-cable-cbl-sast-0556.html

While its obvious which connector goes to JSATA and which are SATA, I don't understand what is the highlighted connector for:

[image: JSATA cable]

I suppose that's the "sideband"? What is it? I can't find any information about it in motherboard or cable datasheets.

Comment: That looks like it's for a USB or audio front panel interface.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/5676/what-is-a-raid-controllers-sideband-cable-used-for